# How to generate random image using image view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

I just followed treehouse course and create my first Fun Fact app.In that they generate a random array quotes.

**Needed:**

I have placed image view using storyboard.Already when pressing one `button` random array quotes will generate.But i need when that same button `pressed` a random image should generate.I am new to swift .!

This is `factbook.swift`

```
struct FactBook {
    // stored in arry to show all quotes
    let factsArray = [
    "You have to dream before your dreams can come true.",

        "To succeed in your mission, you must have single-minded devotion to your goal.",


         "You have to dream before your dreams can come true.",

         "Love your job but don’t love your company, because you may not know when your company stops loving you.",


         "Failure will never overtake me if my definition to succeed is strong enough.",




    ]


    //make a random quote

    func randomFact() -> String {

//        
//        let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
//       

        let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(factsArray.count)
        let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

//        
//        let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
//        let randomNumber = Int(signedRandomNumber)


        return factsArray[randomNumber]
    }

}
```

This is `viewcontroller.swift`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var funFactLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var funFactButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var imgV: UIImageView!

    let factBook = FactBook()
    let colorWheel = ColorWheel()

    //method to define

    //        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "apj")
    //        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()

         self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "apj")!)
        //        let yourImage = UIImage(named: "apj")
//        let imageview = UIImageView(image: yourImage)
//        self.view.addSubview(imageview)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showFunFact() {
        let randomColor = colorWheel.randomColor()
        view.backgroundColor = randomColor
        funFactButton.tintColor = randomColor
        //funFactButton.tintColor = clearcolor

        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution mainly is to use the same approach you have done with the random text. So to sum up, you should have an array of the images, and a function to select a random image. Then call that function from your view controller. A possible implementation to this approach is:

Add this array to your `FactBook`

```
let factsImagesArray = [
    "image1.png",
        "image2.png",
         "image3.png",
         "image4.png",
         "image5.png",
    ]
```

Add this method to your `FactBook`

```
func randomFactImage() -> UIImage {
    let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(factsImageArray.count)
    let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
    let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
    return UIImage(named: factsImageArray[randomNumber])!
}
```

and in your viewcontroller change `showFunFact` to:

```
@IBAction func showFunFact() {
        let randomColor = colorWheel.randomColor()
        view.backgroundColor = randomColor
        funFactButton.tintColor = randomColor
        funFactLabel.text = factBook.randomFact()

        imgV.image = faceBook.randomFactImage()
    }
```

Ofc you should have the image1.png, image2.png ... in your resources

Comment: Thanks ,but i got error in that method on `UIImage`

Comment: what is the error ? did you notice the `!` at the return statement?

Comment: yes i am having image1.jpg,image2.jpg only.but still error in that uiimage

Comment: in which function do you get the error? what is the error?

Comment: I updated the `randomFactImage ` function, re copy paste it please

Comment: To the OP: Typing code into SO there are likely to be small errors. You should not just copy/paste the code people provide and expect it to work. Use the code as a guide and adapt it to your needs, along with fixing any small typos.

Comment: @DuncanC exactly, i wasn't using my xcode so i had some typos, but then in order to help better, i tried the function locally (just the function).

Comment: Sometimes I think it's better to explain what to do but NOT provide code. Newbies don't learn as well if they just copy your code into their project. Better if they have to write code to implement the solution you outline.

Comment: from your code i got three error 1.. In randomFactImage() method i got two errror use of unresolved identifier `factsImageArray`                                         2. in that action method also same error on `factsImageArray`

Comment: @AAAbi probably the name is `factsImagesArray` not `factsImageArray` (notice the **s**)

Comment: @AAAbi, use William's code as an outline. Stop expecting it to work without needing to be cleaned up. Engage your brain and find and fix the problems with that code yourself. Otherwise you'll never learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func randomimage(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //list of Images in array 
    let image : NSArray = [ UIImage(named: "1.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "2.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "3.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "4.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "5.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "6.jpg")!,
        UIImage(named: "7.jpg")!]

    //random image generating method
    let imagerange: UInt32 = UInt32(image.count)
    let randomimage = Int(arc4random_uniform(imagerange))
    let generatedimage: AnyObject = image.objectAtIndex(randomimage)
    self.myimage.image = generatedimage as? UIImage
}
```